# I want to login to google cloud from my NextJS application using Auth0's SAML authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, auth0, saml-2.0

I am setting up SAML for the first time and i do not have knowledge of SAML.
I am considering the following case:

*Auth0 will be used as the SAML IdP.
*Google Cloud is the ServiceProvider.

I want to create an application with the following flow:

1. Create a new NextJS application.
2. Prepare the login page and homepage in NextJS.
3. When clicking login on the login page, transition to Auth0's login page, and authenticate with a username and password.
4. After authentication is successful, return to the NextJS homepage.
5. Click a button from the NextJS homepage to open the Google Cloud console screen (assuming it will open without authentication through SAML).

What I have already done:

I have set up a NextJS application following this guide:  https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/interactive

I have configured the Google Workspace SAML settings in the same application's Addons following this guide:
https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/single-sign-on/outbound-single-sign-on/configure-auth0-saml-identity-provider/configure-auth0-as-idp-for-google-g-suite

I have configured Third-Party SSO in admin.google.com following this guide:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/12032922?hl=en&ref_topic=7579248&sjid=7668804781906083071-AP

Currently,
I can authenticate with an Auth0 with username and password from my localhost application.
Also, I can redirect to Auth0 and login at console-cloud-google-com using a custom domain user from the browser separately.

My question is:
I want to be able to click a button from a NextJS application and transition to GCP using SSO.
Could you tell me what settings are missing?
Additionally, I would appreciate it if you could provide any sample code or documents for reference.